# How do I use spaces in my command for my Discord.py bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am working on a bot, I am working on the db. But I ran into an issue which is providing a space into the file, whenever I do "[bot-prefix]new_file testfile This has spaces in it," it'll only write "This," does anyone have a solution for my issue? (ignore the below comments I had to edit this message for posting privelages, I honestly do wish StackOverflow understood different devs has different styles of programming and that a different question won't *always* help.)

Here is my code for it:

````
async def new_file(ctx, filename: str, data: str):
    newfile = open(f'{filename}.txt',"a+")
    newfile.write(data)
    newfile.close()```
````

Answer (score 1):

You should think of your snake as a list of segments, the first one being the head and the last one being the tail.

```
initialSize = 3
snake = [(240,240)] * InitialSize
```

To draw the snake, loop over the list and draw each segment independently.

```
for segX,segY in snake:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 210, 0), ((segX, segY), (15, 15)))
```

To increase the size of the snake, add a segment to the list by copying the last one:

```
snake += snake[-1:]
```

To make the snake move, shift the segment position by one in the list, then assign the new head position to the first element of the list:

```
snake[1:] = snake[:-1]
snake[0]  = (snakehX,snakehY)
```

Comment: Alright, I will try this, but what does initial size do?

Comment: If you want your snake to start out with a length of 3 segments (for example).  You can start with 1 if your snake begins as a single square.

Comment: How come m y answer ended up on a completely unrelated question (this was originally about making a snake longer in a game) ?